# How to send 2 argument in jinja select?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I can't route 2 argument(skill_id, score) by select form in skill_summary.html.
Here in skill_summary.html, score is set to 2 constant value in url_for, but how can I pass score dynamically as selected to update_skill?

routes.py

```
@app.route("/update_skill/<int:skill_id>/<int:score>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_skill(skill_id, score):
    skill = Skill.query.get_or_404(skill_id)
    skill.score = score
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Score has been updated!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('skill_summary'))

@app.route("/skill_summary")
def skill_summary():
    skills = Skill.query.all()
    return render_template('skill_summary.html', skills=skills)
```

skill_summary.html

```
<form action="{{ url_for('update_skill', skill_id=skill.id, score=1) }}" method='POST'>
  <select name="score">
    {% for score in range(6) %}
    <option value={{score}} {% if score==skill.score %} selected {% endif %}> {{score}} </option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

If I replace to

```
<form action="{{ url_for('update_skill', skill_id=skill.id, score=score)}}", class="form" method="POST">
```

The following error is displayed in the WEB browser.

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'score' is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your route URL like this: `/update_skill/<int:skill_id>/<int:score>`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but what I don't know is skill_summary.html, particularly, ```<form action="{{ url_for('update_skill', skill_id=skill.id, score=2)}}", class="form" method="POST">``` , Currently score=2 is constant value, but I want to dynamically pass as selected value.

Comment: Are you iterating through a `list` of `skills`?

Comment: Yes, it is. skills is query all database.
```
@app.route("/skill_summary")
def skill_summary():

    skills = Skill.query.all()

    return render_template('skill_summary.html', skills=skills)
```

Comment: You are getting `'score' is undefined` error because, you need to pass `score` also, like this: `render_template('skill_summary.html', skills=skills, score=2)` in `skill_summary` method.

Comment: Could you show how are you iterating through all the `skills` in code?

Comment: error was updated to main page, with ```<form action="{{ url_for('update_skill', skill_id=skill.id, score=1)}}", class="form" method="POST">``` no error, but with ```<form action="{{ url_for('update_skill', skill_id=skill.id, score=score)}}", class="form" method="POST">``` I get error ```jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'score' is undefined```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200935/discussion-between-user6508956-and-ngshravil-py).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution while testing flask behavior.

In jinja code, only pass skill_id value to update_skill

```
<form action="{{ url_for('update_skill', skill_id=skill.id) }}" method='POST'>
  <select name="score">
    {% for score in range(6) %}
    <option value={{score}} {% if score==skill.score %} selected {% endif %}> {{score}} </option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

In update_skill only use request.form to get selected value.

```
@app.route("/update_skill/<int:skill_id>", methods=['POST'])
def update_skill(skill_id):
    skill = Skill.query.get_or_404(skill_id)
    skill.score = request.form["score"]
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Score has been updated!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('skill_summary'))
```